# Get last published code from Azure Web App Publish

Tags: azure

I messed up. I needed to reset my computer and wipe it clean. In doing so, I mistakenly committed incorrect code (a lot of it) to source control. Now, going to retrieve it and discovering its the wrong stuff. I have the correct code published - Is it at all possible to get this code that's up in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a copy of the deployed code via the KUDU interface.  Please note that this is the deployed code, and it won't be the source if you are using a compiled language such as C#.

Please see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) for details on how to access the KUDU interface.  If you click on debug console and then powershell, you will see a file browser (picture shown at bottom of blog post).  There is a download button for each folder.  Simply navigate to where your files are stored and download.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Assuming you want the repo not the deployed (compiled) code- Go into Kudu/DebugConsole and grab the **repository** folder from /site/.

It has a clone of your local git repo in it.